# Toggling a recursive fetch request based on React state using `useEffect`

Tags: reactjs, recursion, react-hooks, fetch, use-effect

I am trying to start and stop a recursive fetch request with a button in React. I would also like to have a delay between each request. For this, I decided to use the `useEffect` hook and link it to a boolean state that is controlled by the button. Whenever this state updates, the script inside `useEffect` checks if it is true or false. If it's true, I would like to fetch some necessary data and initiate a recursive fetch function. If it's false, it means the recursive function is already running thus the ongoing request should be cancelled, stopping the recursion, and the `setTimeout` used to achieve the delay between requests should be cleared.

The code below is a mockup of how I attempted to solve this problem. However, it doesn't work, probably for the following reasons:

- The variables `request` and `timeout` are recreated on every rerender. I think this could be solved with the `useRef` hook; however, I'm a beginner with React and haven't managed to get it to work.
- My functions seem to be not getting any state updates; for example, in `recursiveFetch`, `data2` is always `default` when it should contain a new value set by the fetch request in `useEffect`.

I've tried many and many different combinations and ways to get this to work but didn't find any success. How should I approach this problem?

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
    const [executing, setExecuting] = useState(false);

    const [data1, setData1] = useState('default');
    const [data2, setData2] = useState('default');

    const [data3, setData3] = useState('default');

    // I think these variables should be defined with `useRef` but I'm not sure...
    let request;
    let timeout;

    const recursiveFetch = () => {
        request = fetch(`https://website.com/${data2}`, { method: 'POST' })
        .then((res) => {
            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                recursiveFetch();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(executing){
            // Fetch some necessary data
            fetch(`https://example.com/${data1}`)
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    setData2(data.exampleProperty);
                }
            // Call recursive function
            recursiveFetch();
        } else {
            // Cancel ongoing fetch request and clear timeout
            request.cancel();
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    }, [executing])
    return (
        <>
            <Button onClick={() => setExecuting((prev) => !prev)}></Button>
        </>
    );
};

export default Component;
```

Comment: Why would you need to do `fetch` recursively? What API are you calling to that would require this? This feels like a possible [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876).

Comment: @ggorlen I'm quite sure it's not an XY problem as doing `fetch` recursively is exactly what I want to do. Why? It's mainly for an experiment and to learn React.

Comment: @ggorlen Well, as I've said, it's sort of an experiment. Also, I'm not fetching data but making recurring `POST` requests. I have managed to get this to work in vanilla JavaScript a long time ago and I though I should give it a try in React mainly to dive deeper into the usage of hooks. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `recursiveFetch` function isn't exactly recursive since it doesn't actually call itself within its own stack frame. The call is made by an asynchronous function (the callback to `setTimeout`) that runs when the stack is cleared. See [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) for details on when asynchronous functions run.

Secondly, there's no need for repeatedly setting and clearing `setTimeout`s here. That's what `setInterval` is for. Since you're re-rendering anyway when `executing` changes, you can use that to conditionally toggle the interval.

Thirdly, don't forget to return a cleanup function from your `useEffect` that clears your timeout when the component unmounts.

I appreciate that you're experimenting for pedagogical purposes, but it bears mention that the patterns you're exploring aren't the sort of thing you'd see done in React, unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve. Without much motivation for it, it seems best to provide a direct solution that seems to do basically what you're looking to do in a normal, un-fancy way:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [executing, setExecuting] = React.useState(false);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (executing) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("fetched");
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [executing]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>check the browser console to see logs</p>
      <button onClick={() => setExecuting(prev => !prev)}>
        {executing ? "on" : "off"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you need to fetch some data whenever you begin the interval, you might try something like:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [executing, setExecuting] = React.useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState("default");
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!executing) {
      return;
    }
    
    fetch("https://httpbin.org/get")
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(data => setData(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    ;
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("fetched");
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [executing]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>check the browser console to see logs</p>
      <button onClick={() => setExecuting(prev => !prev)}>
        {executing ? "on" : "off"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If the interval shouldn't start until `data` is set (this appears to be your intent, because `data2` is used in the URL), you can move it into the final `then`'s callback in the `fetch` chain. Keep `interval` in the outer scope so it can be cleared and make sure not to start the interval if the component unmounted before the `fetch` response arrived.

If these don't match your use case exactly and aren't tweakable to meet your needs, I recommend providing more details to better motivate why you need to do something more complex.